# Is there a way to delay recovery operations action in Zabbix like with regular operations?

Tags: notifications, action, delay, zabbix

I can configure Zabbix to send me mail warning notifications only if a certain amount of time has passed and the trigger problem is still active on the dashboard.

Now, Zabbix doesn't have an option under "recovery operations" for delay like "Operations" has but is there a way to configure something so I can receive "RESOLVED" mail only if there was a "PROBLEM" mail for a certain trigger in the first place?

The way it works now is - if I set up 'recovery operations' for sending me 'resolved' mail it will send me that regardless if it did or didn't send me 'problem mail'.

I want to do solve this because it's very annoying getting all the notifications but I still need some notifications. Like when a problem is active for more than 20 minutes and I only want to see problem and resolved notifications for that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way out of the box to manage the recovery operation.

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/notifications/action/recovery_operations):

> Recovery operations do not support escalating - all operations are
>   assigned to a single step.

If this is an important issue to you there are some ways to mitigate it, but any workaround that comes to mind is time consuming.

You can implement multiple triggers with tags and tag-bound actions (ie: duplicate triggers with different actions and recovery actions), manage the issue with an agent in your mailbox (horrible!) or write a custom script to be used as default recovery action.

This script should receive the problem ID as a parameter and use it to check via API if it needs to silently close the issue or send an email or set a trigger with a specific tag and use it with another zabbix action etc...